# How to make a placeholder clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, placeholder

On my website, I would like to create an input field with a placeholder like "Password. Example: abcdef", with "abcdef" being clickable. If the user clicks on "abcdef", then the input value change to "abcdef". How can I do that please ? I am ready to use jQuery if it is necessary.

(Obviously, I am not going to do that for a "password" field, this was just an example).

Comment: Hint: Overlay your textbox with an absolutely positioned element containing the text/clickable stuff you need.

Comment: please provide expected html and also show what you have tried. Setting an `input` value within a click handler is fairly trivial

Comment: @techfoobar yes, I think it is a good idea. However, if I put the new div over the textarea, we cannot enter text anymore. If I put the new div under the textarea, we cannot see the div...

Comment: @Arnaud - When you mousedown on the div (overlay), you should hide the div and set focus to the text area. If you click on the example inside the div, you set its text in textarea, hide the div and set focus to the textarea.

Comment: @Arnaud - Check the answer I've posted. I believe that should solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I said, you can do this with an overlay element.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jt05w77x/3/

**Markup**

```
<input type="text">
<div class="placeholder">Name. Ex: <a href="#">John</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.placeholder {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
// position the div
var tbox = $('input[type="text"]'),
       pholder = $('.placeholder')

pholder
    .css({
        top: tbox.offset().top + 'px',
        left: tbox.offset().left + 'px',
        height: tbox.outerHeight() + 'px',
        width: tbox.outerWidth() + 'px',
    })
    .on('mousedown', 'a', function() {
        pholder.hide();
        var text = $(this).text();
        setTimeout(function() {
            tbox.val(text).focus();
        }, 50);
        return false;
    })
    .on('mousedown', function() {
        pholder.hide();
        setTimeout(function() {
            tbox.val('').focus();
        }, 50);
    });

tbox.on('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') pholder.show(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/rtgmr68L/

```
$('#val').on('focus', function () {
    val = $(this).attr('placeholder')
    $(this).attr('value', val)
})
```

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I was looking for a placeholder in which only a part of the text is clickable.